# An error occurred after deployment in the environment

Tags: spartacus-storefront

May I know what cause this issue?

[image]

This is the issue after we deployed in our environment but when I tested in my local and connected to our environment it's working fine.

Comment: this is because your deployment environments server doesn't have browser apis such as document,window,etc. I asked a similar question earlier, you might wanna take a look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62388078/referenceerror-document-is-not-defined-while-using-angular-8-ngxusefulswiper

Comment: can you please provide the error message observed in Chrome development tool console?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. There is an ssr issue on the recaptcha language on app module.

 {
      provide: RECAPTCHA_SETTINGS,
      useValue: sessionStorage.getItem('lang'),
    },

it seems sessionStorage is not defined.